# Google App Engine: close .put() and .get() race condition?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm putting some data in the datastore via entity.put(), then soon thereafter reading from the datastore (getting data that includes the just put entity) via a .get().

The .get() data is correct, but often the order of it doesn't make sense:

```
SELECT * FROM entityName
WHERE someThing = 'value'
ORDER BY votes DESC, lastTouchedTimestamp DESC
```

Will return the correct entities (updated to include new data from the aforementioned .put()) but in an order that is incorrect (i.e. the votes and/or lastTouchedTimestamp actually aren't in order)

Pretty new to GAE so sorry if there is some simple thing I'm overlooking.

EDIT/ADDITION:

each entity has a vote integer. the SELECT should return entities in order of votes like: 10,8,7,7,1, but instead sometimes returns 10,7,8,7,1, for example.

Comment: What do you mean by incorrect.. can you give a small example with the number of votes/timestamp per row? To present somehow the type of inconstancy..

Comment: @Lipis added an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Engine has no guarantee concerning index update timing.

In your example it means that index data is 10,7,7,7,1 but the returned results are actual objects (which are updated) so you notice that ordering is off because you expect 8 for one of the entries.

If you use a [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Query_Projection), you'll see 10,7,7,7,1.

Answer (score 6):

What you're describing is in App Engine terms *not* a .get() call but a *query*.  Proper .get() calls specify a key and are not subject to this race.  (Nor are ancestor queries.)  For more background info about this topic, read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Datastore_Writes_and_Data_Visibility

You're lucky that you're getting the updated entity in your query results at all -- that's because the entity as it existed before your .put() call still matched the query.  You're getting the correct value in the entity because query results (except for projection queries as @tesdal mentioned) are accessed by key; but you're getting the wrong ordering because the ordering is taken from the index.